# Group By a nullable column

Tags: sql, oracle

As you know Oracle treats NULLs as one "value" in GROUP BY queries. Is there a workaround solution to group data treating NULLs as different values each. For example:

table t:

```
colA     colB
 A         1 
 A         5 
<null>     3 
<null>     2
```

`select colA, min(colB) from t group by colA` returns:

```
colA     colB
 A         1 
<null>     2
```

but i want a query to return:

```
colA     colB
 A         1 
<null>     3 
<null>     2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT colA, MIN(colB)
FROM t
WHERE colA IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY colA
UNION ALL
SELECT colA, colB
FROM t
WHERE colA IS NULL
```

Comment: Correct. Thx so much. How did i miss that?

Answer (score 6):

@lc's answer is a great one, but just for the sport here is another solution:

```
SELECT  colA, min(colB)
FROM t
GROUP BY nvl(colA, rownum),colA
```

And [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d5954/6) is a sqlfiddle demo

Comment: Yep, that's very correct, too :) However a little bit slower that Ic's solution.